# unable to run expo on IOS simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

i've a problem with expo, who doesn’t work on my ios simulator,
on the simulator i have the following message : 'There was a problem running Expo'
[screen of ios emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm99G.png)

Everything is ok on android emulator,  i tried to reinstall expo on my mac and iphone emulator, i check a lot of post but i didn’t see exactly the same error,
this issue May be due to the fact that I changed my computer and that I copied all my files from the old computer.

if anybody can help me, I would be grateful
thx u.

Comment: what is the SDK version on your project? does this happen if you run `expo client:install:ios` in your project?

Comment: @brentvatne , actually it's SDK 38.0.0. and yes it's happen

Comment: @nartco have you tried deleting your node_modules and reinstalling your packages?

Comment: @Phobos , yes but doesn’t change anything

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the expo folder in the project?

Comment: ok actually it work, when i create a new project, but not on my current project